# Fetching rows in adf view object programmatically

Tags: oracle, oracle-adf

Whenever I try to fetch the view object rows programmatically, I only get the first row. Please help.

**Here is my code:**

```
BindingContext BContext=BindingContext.getCurrent();
System.out.println(1);
//BindingContainer bindings= (BindingContainer)bctx.getCurrent().getCurrentBindingsEntry();
BindingContainer bindings = (BindingContainer)BContext.getCurrent().getCurrentBindingsEntry();
DCBindingContainer dc = (DCBindingContainer)BindingContext.getCurrent().getCurrentBindingsEntry();
DCIteratorBinding iterBind= dc.findIteratorBinding("UsersView1Iterator");
ViewObject vo=iterBind.getViewObject();  
vo.executeQuery();
RowSetIterator rsIterator = vo.createRowSetIterator(null);
rsIterator.reset();
while (rsIterator.hasNext()) {
       Row row = rsIterator.next();
       String s=(String)row.getAttribute("Username");
       String s1=(String)row.getAttribute("Password");
       System.out.println(row.getAttribute("Username"));
       System.out.println(row.getAttribute("Password"));
       if(s.equals(user) && s1.equals(Pass)){
            System.out.println(row.getAttribute("Username"));
            FacesMessage fm=new FacesMessage(message.toString());
            fm.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO);
            FacesContext context=FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            context.addMessage(null, fm);
            System.out.println("valid");
            return "Success";
       }else{
            FacesMessage fm=new FacesMessage(message1.toString());
            fm.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO);
            FacesContext context=FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            System.out.println("invalid");
            context.addMessage(null, fm);System.out.println(20);   
            return "fail";
       }       
 }  
 rsIterator.closeRowSetIterator();  
 return null;
```

Comment: Please take a look at [How to ask?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before you ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

If the user and password matches you return "Success" but if it does not match it returns "fail". Try that code instead:

```
while (rsIterator.hasNext()) {
       Row row = rsIterator.next();
       String s=(String)row.getAttribute("Username");
       String s1=(String)row.getAttribute("Password");
       System.out.println(row.getAttribute("Username"));
       System.out.println(row.getAttribute("Password"));
       if(s.equals(user) && s1.equals(Pass)){
            System.out.println(row.getAttribute("Username"));
            FacesMessage fm=new FacesMessage(message.toString());
            fm.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO);
            FacesContext context=FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            context.addMessage(null, fm);
            System.out.println("valid");
            return "Success";
       }       
 }
rsIterator.closeRowSetIterator();  
FacesMessage fm=new FacesMessage(message1.toString());
fm.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO);
FacesContext context=FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
System.out.println("invalid");
context.addMessage(null, fm);System.out.println(20);   
return "fail";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DCBindingContainer bindings =
(DCBindingContainer)BindingContext.getCurrent().getCurrentBindingsEntry();
DCIteratorBinding dcIteratorBindings =
bindings.findIteratorBinding("DocumentsView1Iterator");

// Get all the rows of a iterator
Row[] rows = dcIteratorBindings.getAllRowsInRange();
for (Row row : rows) {
    String Username=(String)row.getAttribute("Username");
    String Password=(String)row.getAttribute("Password");
    System.out.println("Check"+depname);
}
```